# Instance Segmentation: Categorisation of architectures (one-stage / proposal based / etc.)

Tags: computer-vision

I am currently working on the topic of instance segmentation. So far I have found three possibilities for categorising the architectures:

1. one-stage / two-stage architectures
2. proposal based / proposal free architectures
3. detection followed by segmentation / labelling pixels followed by clustering

Can anyone tell me the difference between these categorisations? For example, is one-stage also proposal free and based on labelling pixels followed by clustering ?

Unfortunately, I can't specify this myself.

Here are a few of my sources so far:

- Sharma, Rabi & Saqib, Muhammad & Lin, C. & Blumenstein, Michael. (2022). A Survey on Object Instance Segmentation. SN Computer Science.
- Hafiz, Abdul Mueed & Bhat, Ghulam. (2020). A survey on instance segmentation: state of the art. International Journal of Multimedia Information Retrieval.
- Carranza-García, Manuel et al. “On the Performance of One-Stage and Two-Stage Object Detectors in Autonomous Vehicles Using Camera Data.” Remote. Sens. 13 (2020): 89.